# difference between MAP and MML

Tags: bayesian, gaussian-process

I am new to Bayesian inference and Gaussian Processes. I am writing to ask what is the difference between MAP (maximum a posteriori) and MML (maximum marginal likelihood). They both seem to enable us to infer the hyperparameters. Is it simply that the latter fully Bayesian while the other is not?